# Java: How would I convert a String representing an array into an array?

Tags: java

If I have something like:

```
"{3, 5, 62}"
```

How would I convert it to an array like:

```
{3, 5, 62}
```

I don't really have a clue how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
String s="{a, b, c}";
String[] sArray = s.substring(1, s.length() - 1).trim().split("\\s*,\\s*");
int [] res = new int[sArray.length];
for (int i=0;i< res.length; i++) {
    res[i] = Integer.parseInt(sArray[i]);
}
```

This should do.

Comment: Instead of using trim(), better to use a regex for split() that removes the comma and all intervening spaces.

Comment: Thanks. I have transfomed "," in "\\s*,\\s*. However a trim() before the split is necessary...